# Is there a way to rename these columns in a dataframe from yfinance?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, yfinance

I used yfinance to pull the dividends for 10 companies. Using a loop I have a dataframe with the dividends from the 10 companies, I am happy with the layout of the dataframe and the values. I am struggling to find a way to rename the columns in the dataframe below. Are there any adjustments to the loop that can be made to get it done? If anyone has a better way of writing the code please let me know.

```
   stocks_list = ['MRP.JO', 'WHL.JO', 'SHP.JO' ,'AVI.JO', 'PIK.JO', 'BVT.JO' ,'SBK.JO', 'FSR.JO', 'NED.JO', 'SPP.JO']
a=[]
for str in stocks_list:
    stock = yf.Ticker(str)
    a.append(stock.dividends)
    data = pd.DataFrame(a)
    
divi_df = data.T.fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

The code and dataframe are attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Yds.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDF42.png)

Comment: I'm not sure how you would like to modify the column names because the state of the data is unknown, but it is possible with `data.columns = stocks_list`

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Stupid of me not to think of such a simple solution. Still new to coding

Comment: Everyone starts with a beginner. enjoy!